# Eclipse content assist doesn't recognize std::thread, but compiles correctly

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, stdthread

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Steps I took to reproduce:

1. Create a new C++ project (New -> C++ -> Hello World project), which I called `TestStdThread`
2. Change the code in the main file to this:

   ```
   #include <thread>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       std::cout << "You have " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << " cores." << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Go to TestStdThread -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler, and change the **Command** options from `g++` to `g++ -std=c++11`
4. Go to TestStdThread -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes, add `/usr/include` to the **Include paths (-I)**, and add `pthread.h` to the **Include files (-include)**
5. Go to TestStdThread -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries, add `pthread` to the **Libraries (-l)**, and add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the **Library search path (-L)**
6. TestStdThread -> Build Project
7. Click "Run"

There were no build errors. Eclipse told me that the project had errors and asked if I wanted to run it anyway, and when I said yes, the output was, correctly: `You have 4 cores.`. However, Eclipse still underlined the `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` part in red, and reported it (on hover) as "Function 'hardware_concurrency' could not be resolved," and `std::thread` didn't show up when typing `std::` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

This is the bash command I used to find where my `pthread` files were located within `/usr` (`/usr/share` omitted as it contains lots of doc files that I'm not looking for):

```
llama@llama-Satellite-E55-A:/usr$ find -name "*pthread*" -not -path "./share/*"
./include/pthread.h
./include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/pthread-stubs.pc
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpgme-pthread.so.11.11.0
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpgme-pthread.so.11
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
./lib/perl/5.18.2/bits/pthreadtypes.ph
./lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
```

Comment: `#include <thread>` maybe ?

Comment: @vsoftco Whoops, that was a copy/paste error. I did indeed have that in my original code, of course ;)

Comment: Try to re-index the project.

Comment: @vsoftco Tried that; it still doesn't work.

Comment: works on my end (`OS X` `gcc 4.9`), no red markings, however I added the `-std=c++11` flag under Project Properties/C++ Build/Settings/GCC C++ Compiler/Miscellaneous (Other flags), but I guess it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @vsoftco Tried that; still no luck :/ Are you on Ubuntu as well? (edit) Oh, hmm. It may be an ubuntu-specific issue then; I have no idea what could be causing that though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Project` -> `Properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Preprocessor include paths, etc` -> `Providers` -> `CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings` and append `-std=c++11` to the compiler specs.

You can also do this for all projects going to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Settings` -> `Discovery` and append `-std=c++11` to the `CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings` specs.

Make sure to reindex your project afterwards.

These instructions are for Eclipse Luna (4.4.0), for previous versions the paths are similar.

Comment: Does reindex mean Rebuild?