# Thread could not be resolved in eclipse 4.7

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, mingw

I've installed **MinGW**(gcc 6.3.0) and **Eclipse 4.7** on Windows 8.1. I could compile and run other programs without any issue. But when I was using `thread` it is showing that `thread was not declared in this scope`. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835081/eclipse-content-assist-doesnt-recognize-stdthread-but-compiles-correctly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184177/c-error-type-stdthread-could-not-be-resolved-eclipse-mars-4-5-ubuntu-12) but both no avail. Could somebody help me fix this?
Here is the code I've treid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo(){
    std::cout<<"thread function \n";}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread t1(foo);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure about the C++11 features. I've tried Lambda function example from [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/cplusplus11.php) page(last example) and it is working fine.

Comment: You *do* include `<thread>`? And use `std::thread` (or `using namespace std` which is not really recommended)? Perhaps if you show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: When I use `std::thread` error reads `'thread' is not a member of 'std'`. Of course I've included  `<thread>`.

Comment: What version of GCC do you have installed?

Comment: Also, you say "I could compile and run other programs without any issue". Have you used any other C++11 (or higher) functionality in those programs?

Comment: Lambda functions are working fine.